# Loading A CSS File From Django Template

Tags: css, django

I have looked through several answers for loading CSS pages. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Basically, I believe my question should be how do I get staticfiles installed?

I am confused about the settings in settings.py, and I get this error when trying to run collectstatic.

```
./manage.py collectstatic
Unknown command: 'collectstatic'
```

In settings.py, I've added

```
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

to INSTALLED_APS

and

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
 "/home/amr/django/static_media",
)

STATIC_ROOT = "/home/amr/django/static_media"
```

The error I'm getting is there is no module staticfiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are running an old version of django, the staticfiles application is included in the latest 1.3-alpha or trunk version. To find out which version of django your project is running on try running the following command on a shell

```
$ python -c "import django; print django.get_version()"
```

Answer (score 2):

That documentation is for the development version of Django. If you're running a stable version then you should examine the appropriate docs by clicking on the version number at the top of the article.

Comment: This is where I load the css file in my base template<html>
    <!-- Test Comment -->
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Town of Arlington Water Department AMR System{% endblock %} </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static_media/amr.css" />
    </head>
This is the css file (for now) body{ background-color: gray;} 
p { color: blue; } 
h3{ color: white; }   I've added this to urls.py     (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': '/home/amr/django'}),
    Where can I check to see why this is not loading?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I looked for the 1.2.3 documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Try running it with sudo. Available commands are limited based on your access level.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that the docs for 1.2 here:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/

are the same as 1.3

however, this is obviously totally wrong.

So the first answer here is frustratingly misleading.